# Fetch email address from NVARCHAR2 DATATYPE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table in which there is a column of NVARCHAR2 datatype which holds a string.
The string contains some Email Ids which I require to fetch in a comma separated manner.

Below is the test data --

```
create table nvarchar2_email (email_reject nvarchar2(1000));

insert into nvarchar2_email values ('com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException:     javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <manoj.dalai@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <santoshi.k@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <biswajit-kumar.p@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table');

insert into nvarchar2_email values ('com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;  nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <manoj.dalai@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <santoshi.k@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table');
```

I am trying to use the below SQL but it is repeating the Email Ids !!

```
select email_rejetc, listagg(REGEXP_substr (email_rejetc,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}', 1,level), ',') within group (order by email_rejetc) invalid_email
from   nvarchar2_email
connect by level <= REGEXP_count (email_rejetc,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') 
group by EMAIL_REJETC
```

Here the required output is like

```
manoj.dalai@gmail.com,santosh.k@gmail.com,biswajit-kumar@gmail.com
```

Number of emails can VARY in different rows of the table;

My DB is :
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  (select          listagg (regexp_substr(cast(e.email_reject as varchar2(1000)),'<(.*?@.*?)>',1,level,'',1),',') 
                             within group (order by e.email_reject)
         from            dual
         connect by      level <= regexp_count (e.email_reject,'<.*?@.*?>')
         )       as emails                         

from     nvarchar2_email e
;
```

P.s.

There seem to be an issue with regexp_substr and nvarchar that causes each character in the result to be preceded by \0.
Tested on Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, it would appear that the e-mail address is always presented as `<aaaa@bbbb>`, meaning a `<`, a string with a `@` in the middle, and a `>` sign.

You could try something like this (cannot check syntax, so you might need to do some tests):

```
  SUBSTR(<input string>                                             , 
         INSTR(<input string>,'<') + 1                              ,
         (INSTR(<input string>,'>') - INSTR(<input string>,'<') - 2
        ) ;
```

This will yield the **FIRST** e-mail address within the string. You may use the same concept (providing a string without the first section that contains the first e-mail address) in a loop to extract additional addresses within the same string.

I can't see a way to do this through a single "SELECT" statement because each string may have several (and not all string the same number of) addresses.

One option to investigate is to implement a recursive select (Oracle supports this), but it will be much more complex.

Personally, I would go with the approach suggested above.

Comment: I tried using INSTR SUBSTR at my first attempt but it always gives me the first email id only whereas if i declare the position of <,> in INSTR function to move to second email address i need to do this in SQL only as it is requirement.

Comment: Indeed. After you find the first one, you need  to move the start of the next search (for `<`) to **after** the end of the e-mail address. That is why I mentioned that you would need to implement a simple loop for each string.